# Javascript listen for image load call and change src before image loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, timing

I'm running a front-end script for this to test out some images, and timing is funky, which makes this unique.

I need a way using Javascript to catch an img when the request to the endpoint is made to load the image. I know the image endpoint ( say www.domain.com/directory/number.jpg ), and I want to change that and point to a different endpoint ( say www.differentdomain.com/directory/number_2.jpg ).
I've tried finding the element and changing the src attribute, yet the element seems to be loading onto the page after Document Ready, so there is a long interval of polling the page to find the element.

This is all front-end, to run as the page loads and after, waiting for a user action.

Please note, a setInterval that continuously runs doesn't catch this as precisely as I'd like and it adds a lot of resources to the page for it to run long enough. What other options are there?

---

I've tried using jquery and polling for the selector in a setInterval, yet this adds a lot of resources to the page to poll every 10 ms and catch this. The problem becomes assigning the event listening to an element that's not yet on the page.
I've just come across Javascript Promises - and am curious if there's a way that would work, though I'm open to ideas.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to know when the image is loaded?

Comment: Yes, then at that point I can see how long it's taking and also call another function.

Comment: Since you are adding an eventListener to an element that is being created dynamically, you can use `MutationObserver` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change the src attribute with an IIFE function instead of Document Ready? As much as I understood you are having problems with the slow load of the image element. With IIFE your code executes immediately without document is ready.

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/obLw7n1q/2/) example with Document Ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //some code
}
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/obLw7n1q/1/) example with IIFE

```
!function (){
    //some code
}();
```

P.S I'm sorry if i misunderstood your question.

Comment: unfortunately this is the opposite -- the images I'm waiting for don't exist on the DOM yet, so immediately executing a function will result with a null value for any css selector.